# Access audit trail data outside of salesforce

Tags: apex, after-trigger, code, setup-audit-log, audit-fields

I need to pass audit trail data to informatica. Can anyone suggest how informatica extract the data.
is there any way to query audit trail or any standard api to fetch data

Answer (score 0):

You can query the [SetupAuditTrail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) as a normal object. The fields available on this object are in the documentation, or you can describe this object. In order to query the data, the user must have sufficient privileges to see this data in the UI.

Comment: thanks sfdc fox